# using selenium with gradle

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, gradle, selenium-chromedriver

Ive been struggling to get chromedriver working in java with gradle for days now.

Ive had a bunch of suggestions. None of which worked. (The things commented out are suggestions ive tried)

my whole project is here https://github.com/learncss666/gradle_chromedriver

the 3 things below are

my main java file, my build.gradle and the output from my cmd line

Scrapper.java

```
package com.scrapper;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Scrapper {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String x = "hello world lol";

        System.out.println(x);
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Users/tgmjack/Desktop/jda test/q4/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/web/web-form.html");
    }
}
```

###########

build.gradle

```
 plugins {
    id 'java'
 }

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.scrapper.Scrapper'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '4.16.1'
    implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-chrome-driver', version: '4.16.1'
    // the 2 lines below didnt fix anything. they are from https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/seleniumhq.github.io/blob/trunk/examples/java/build.gradle#L13-L14
    //testImplementation 'org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:4.16.1'
    //testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.10.0'
}
```

###################

output

```
C:\Users\tgmjack\Desktop\java\New folder>gradlew build

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
C:\Users\tgmjack\Desktop\java\New folder>java -jar "build/libs/New folder.jar"
Error: Unable to initialize main class com.scrapper.Scrapper
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver
```

1. why isnt this working?
2. how can i fix this?
3. what else do you need to know

Comment: You're trying to execute the JAR file built by the `jar` task added by the Java Plugin. That task was executed because the `build` task directly or indirectly depends on it. However, the JAR file built by the `jar` task does not, by default, include the dependencies. The JAR file is not a so-called fat/uber/shadowed JAR file. Nor were the dependencies copied into the `build/libs` folder. In short, the Selenium library is not being put on the class-path/module-path with the `java -jar "build/libs/New folder.jar"` command, and so its classes cannot be found.

Comment: How to fix this depends on what exactly you want to do, though all solutions involve ensuring Selenium ends up on the class-path/module-path at run-time. One option is to apply the [Application Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) and execute `./gradlew run`. Another option is to create a "shadowed" JAR file with the [Gradle Shadow Plugin](https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/) and executing it like you are know (i.e., with `java -jar <file>`).

Comment: when you say apply he aplication plugins im not sure what you mean. 

I have all the same plugins as this example here 

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/seleniumhq.github.io/blob/trunk/examples/java/build.gradle

Comment: That example has Selenium as a **test** dependency. You're trying to use it as a "main" dependency (i.e., in code under `src/main/java`). So, your scenario is slightly different from said example. And your build file only applies the [Java Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#java_plugin). Read the documentation for the [Application Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html) to understand how it works, including how to apply it and how to configure it (make sure to look at the Groovy examples since you're using the Groovy DSL).